# Sonar C# runner failure - "Invalid value of sonar.tests..."

Tags: c#, sonar-runner

Sonar 5.6.1, MsBuild.SonarQube.Runner 2.1, Windows 8.1

When I use the runner to analyse a solution, it fails on the 'end' component.  The most relevant error line from the console is:

ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.tests for 0347AEA0-AA8A-48D4-ACF3-D9D7B3ED28B0

The GUID appears to represent a project within my solution.  I searched through all of the files within the working area for the text "sonar.tests" and identified that the problem lies within the sonar-project.properties file that was generated by one of the earlier components.  It contains a line that starts like this:

0347AEA0-AA8A-48D4-ACF3-D9D7B3ED28B0.sonar.tests=\

There then follows a (massive - too big to show here) comma-separated list of files.

BUG: The comma character being used to delimit entries is a legal character within a file path on the Windows operating system.  Several of the file paths within the list contain one or comma characters.  The runner trips when it encounters such a file path.

The file list contains not only source files, but also files containing test data.  The files containing comma characters are test data.

This failure is a show-stopper for us when using the MsBuild.SonarQube.Runner component.  Removal of the comma characters from the file names isn't practicable, nor is moving the test files within the folder structure.